# Compile Error when installing anchor

Tags: anchor, windows

When I try to install anchor following the instruction in the documentation with,

`cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.24.1 anchor-cli --locked`

I get this error:

```
error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.25.0 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor?tag=v0.25.0#6baed77e)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installvsEsrn`

Caused by:
  failed to download `adler v1.0.2`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\x\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\adler-1.0.2\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  TOML parse error at line 1, column 1
    |
  1 |
    | ^
  Unexpected ``
  Expected key or end of input
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Windows and trying to compile the Anchor CLI, is that right? If so, I would try installing and using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and trying that way. Rust seems to often struggle on Windows based systems.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try changing the tag to v0.25.0 or v0.24.2
since previous versions of anchor-lang get removed

[image]